# Shiny: How to change a background colour of a column?

Tags: r, shiny

I've got a **fluidRow** with three **columns** containing some widgets. Is it possible to change a colour of the middle column (or all widgets in this column) ?

For example: white column - gray column - white column

Comment: For colouring (or, more generally, styling) individual objects, @Barranka's answer is the way to go. If you want to change a group of objects, you should look into [using CSS stylesheets](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) with your App.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you can add style to an element; something like this:

```
column(3, style = "background-color:#4d3a7d;", ...)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: There's also a simple, `wellPanel()` that you can encapsulate items with to turn it grey.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished reactively with the [shinyjs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjs/shinyjs.pdf) package. You can assign an "id" to your column and add/remove/toggle a CSS class in response to the UI. Modifying the example in the 'shinyjs' docs:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(), # Set up shinyjs

      inlineCSS(list(.red = "background: red",
                     .blue = "background: blue")),
      fluidRow(
        column(3, id = "col1",
         actionButton("btn1", "Click me"),
        ),
        column(6, id = "col2",
               actionButton("btn2", "Click me too")
        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      observeEvent(input$btn1, {
        toggleClass("col1", "red")
      })
      observeEvent(input$btn2, {
        toggleClass("col2", "blue")
    })
    }
  )
}
```